# Why is Selenium unable to find elements on some sites?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using a python version of Selenium to capture comments on a Chinese website.

The website is https://v.douyu.com/show/kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz

I want to find this *span* element. In Chinese, this is called "弹幕列表".

[image]

I tried the absolute path like:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/body/demand-video-app/main/div[2]/demand-video-helper//div/div[1]/a[3]/span')
```

But it returns *NoSuchElementException*. I just thought that maybe this site has a protection mechanism. However, I don't know much about Selenium and would like to ask for help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make sure,this element is not in a iframe.And maybe the element is still not rendered out for the moment. You should just wait for a moment by `sleep`

Comment: #shadow-root Has certain properties.

Comment: There's a shadow DOM. That's why you are not getting it.

Comment: I updated the answer to get all the information at once.

Comment: Sort the data by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you use `Selenium` because `requests` can't capture the value.

If it's not what you want to do, don’t read my answer.

Because you are `requests.get(url='https://v.douyu.com/show/kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz')`

You need to find the source of the data `ApiUrl` on `F12 Network`.

In fact, his source of information is

`https://v.douyu.com/wgapi/vod/center/getBarrageListByPage` +  `parameter`

↓

```
https://v.douyu.com/wgapi/vod/center/getBarrageListByPage?vid=kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz&forward=0&offset=-1
```

Although I can't help you solve the Selenium problem.

But I will use the following methods to get the data.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://v.douyu.com/wgapi/vod/center/getBarrageListByPage?vid=kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz&forward=0&offset=-1'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
print(res)
for i in res['data']['list']:
    print(i)
```

Get All Data

```
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://v.douyu.com/wgapi/vod/center/getBarrageListByPage?vid=kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz&forward=0&offset=-1'
while True:
    res = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
    next_json = res['data']['pre']
    if next_json == -1:
        break
    for i in res['data']['list']:
        print(i)
    url = f'https://v.douyu.com/wgapi/vod/center/getBarrageListByPage?vid=kDe0W2q5bB2MA4Bz&forward=0&offset={next_json}'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226385/discussion-on-answer-by-dudulu-why-is-selenium-unable-to-find-elements-on-some-s). Please remember to update the answer with all relevant information.